# Swift - Converting RSSI to Distance

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, rssi

I was doing some work using the CoreBluetooth API and ran into a problem. All of the places I have looked, they say that to convert RSSI (Signal Strength of Bluetooth), you must do things like:

`Distance = 10 ^ ((Measured Power – RSSI)/(10 * N))`

And:

```
var txPower = -59 //hard coded power value. Usually ranges between -59 to -65

if (rssi == 0) {
  return -1.0; 
}

var ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
if (ratio < 1.0) {
  return Math.pow(ratio,10);
}
else {
  var distance =  (0.89976)*Math.pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;    
  return distance;
}
```

I have tried all of the above and everything I could find. None of it gets me the accurate measurements from about 0.5 meters to around 5 - 7 meters of distance between.

My code to do so is making both phones using the app as a central and peripheral Bluetooth and in my `didDiscoverPeripheral` callback from `CentralManager`, I get the RSSI - which I want to convert to a distance (meter, feet).

**Along with that:**

I also need to find out how to get the Measured Power (RSSI Strength at 1 meter) of iPhones as it would really help in the accurate calculations.

Also, what does `environmental factor` mean in terms of Bluetooth? What do the different environmental factors mean (which have the range of 2-4). Is there a way to change or increase the `Broadcasting Power value` of the Apple Device?

**Basically, I am looking for an accurate RSSI to distance formula which works from distances from 0.5 meter to 5-7 meters**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is a common solution:

```
pow(10, ((-56-Double(rssi))/(10*2)))*3.2808
```

It was good for most distances but got very inaccurate as you get close or too far, so I ended up using bins kind of like Apple's iBeacons (`Unknown`, `Far`, `Near`, `Immediate`). If the raw RSSI is less than `-80`, then it is **far**, if it is more than `-50`, then it is **immediate**, and if it is between those two, it is **near**. This solution worked for me.